# Save minimum during while on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, while-loop, save

hello i' m writing a code with a while loop, during the iterations i need to save a value of the minim of a function. Now in my code i save the last value of the iteration but i want the lowest value and not the last one, how can a resolve it?? hers' s my code (i want to remember that this code's running during a while)

```
particelle = 30;               % numero delle particelle
it  = 50;                      % massimo numero di iterazioni
var = 5;                       % numero di variabili del problema
ls = 1;                        % limite superiore
li = 0;                        % limite inferiore
c2 =0.1;                      % parametro PSO 
c1 = 0.1;                     % parametro PSO 
w =0.9;                        % inerzia del PSO

% Parametri del benchmark
Io   =   3.195366750697098e-9;
Iirr =   1.073577407858;
Rp   =   0.783526109678138e+5;
Rs   =   1.18407328046765;
n    =   1.33752492449578;

% Limiti da considerare 
Io_low = Io - (Io * 0.1);               % valore basso togliamo il 10   per cento
Io_high = Io + (Io * 0.1);              % valore alto sommiamo il 10 per cento
Iirr_low = Iirr - (Iirr * 0.1);         % valore basso togliamo il 10 per cento
Iirr_high = Iirr + (Iirr * 0.1);        % valore alto sommiamo il 10 per cento
Rp_low = Rp - (Rp * 0.1);               % valore basso togliamo il 10   per cento
Rp_high = Rp + (Rp * 0.1);              % valore alto sommiamo il 10 per cento
Rs_low = Rs - (Rs * 0.1);               % valore basso togliamo il 10 per cento
Rs_high = Rs + (Rs * 0.1);              % valore alto sommiamo il 10 per cento
n_low = n - (n * 0.1);                  % valore basso togliamo il 10 per cento
n_high = n + (n * 0.1);                 % valore alto sommiamo il 10 per cento

x_low = [Rs_low, n_low, Io_low, Iirr_low, Rp_low ];
x_high = [Rs_high, n_high, Io_high, Iirr_high, Rp_high];

fitness1 = @fitness;          % funzione di fitness


pos = rand(particelle, var);            % posizione delle particelle
vel = 1e-3*rand(particelle, var) ;      % velocità delle particelle
pers  = pos ;                           % personale delle particelle
glob = min(pers);                       % minimo di ogni colonna            
glob = repmat(glob,particelle,1);       % minimo globale uguale per ogni particella           

fitness_corrente = zeros(particelle,1);              % inizializziamo la matrice fitness_corrente che conterrà tutti i valori del fitness di ogni singola particella 
h = zeros(particelle,var);                           % inizializziamo la matrice per 
for i = 1: particelle
h(i,:) = x_low + (pos(i,:).*(x_high-x_low));     % normalizziao i limiti delle particelle
fitness_corrente(i,:) = fitness1(h(i,:));        % fitness della prima popolazione normalizzata
end 

% assegnamo il valore di fitness di ogni particella a fitness_personale
fitness_pers = fitness_corrente;

% indidichiamo con fitness_globale il minimo valore ottenuto dalla fitness e la posizione che occupa x è la particella con ilvalore minimo di fitness
[fitness_glob, minimo] = min(fitness_pers);

%% Main
iter = 1 ;                                    % Contatore 
while  ( iter < it )                          % Finchè non arriviamo a 50 continua 
iter = iter + 1;

% Assegnamo i nuovi valori al personale se ce ne è bisogno
for i = 1:particelle
for j = 1: var
    if pos(i,j) < pers(i,j)
        pers(i,j) = pos(i,j);
    end 
end
end
% implementiamo il valore globale
glob = min(pers);                       % minimo di ogni colonna            
glob = repmat(glob,particelle,1);               % minimo globale uguale per ogni particella           

% implementiamo ancora velocità e posizione
 vel = w*vel + c1*((pers-pos)) + c2*((glob-pos));
 vel(vel<=-0.99) = -0.1;
 pos = pos + vel; 
 con = 0;
% vediamo se le particelle sono all' interno
for i = 1:particelle
for k = 1:var
    if pos(i,k) < li || pos(i,k) > ls
        pos(i,:) = rand(1,var);
        con = con +1;
    end 
end 
end

% vediamo di nuovo il fitness della singola particella normalizzata
for i = 1: particelle
h(i,:) = x_low + (pos(i,:).*(x_high-x_low));     % normalizziao i limiti delle particelle
fitness_corrente(i,:) = fitness1(h(i,:));        % fitness della nuova popolazione
if fitness_corrente(i,:) < fitness_pers(i,:)     % se il fitness della nuova popolazione è minore di quello della vecchia popolazione
    fitness_pers(i,:) = fitness_corrente(i,:);   % assegna il valore di quel fitness alla nuova posizione 
end

end 

[temporaneo, m] = min( fitness_pers);       % temporaneo serve esclusivamente a vedere se il minimo è diminuito rispetto a prima
if temporaneo < fitness_glob
fitness_glob = temporaneo;
minimo = m;                                  % riassegnamo così anche la posizione del fitness globale
end

end % fine del loop


disp(fitness_glob);                         % fitness minimo
disp(h(minimo,:));
```

This is the complete test and the function fitness is this one but you can use another with 5 variables

```
function [ f ] = fitness(x)

Rs       = x(1);
n        = x(2);
Io       = x(3);
Iirr_ref = x(4);
Rp       = x(5);

load datatest_bench1.txt;
V = datatest_bench1(:,1);
I = datatest_bench1(:,2);

for i=1:length(V)
    Ieval(i) = I_bench1(Rs,Rp,Io,Iirr_ref,n,273.15+45,V(i));
    f(i)     = (Ieval(i)-I(i));      
end
    f = mean(abs(Ieval(i)-I(i)));
```

end

Comment: `min = m;` will make the code run inappropriately

Comment: You are using function `min` _and_ defining a variable called `min`, which shadows the function. You should change that variable name.

Comment: yes but i m using a variable called minimo, i wrote min just to let you understand

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do this by setting your minimum as a vector that iterates with your function, for example:

```
for a = 1:10
   number = rand(10);
   minimum(a) = min(number);
end
```

at the end you will have the minimum as a vector that have the same length as the time you have iterated. You can then do another minimum on the vector to obtain the minimum of the whole iteration process.

In your case, you can simply put the iterator in to calling the function; if you are using while, you could put a constant (initially set to 1) and add one to it each time and use it as your vector index.

```
a = 1;
while (some condition)
    conditions
    [temp(a), m(a)] = min (fitness_pers); 
    a= a+1;
end
```

Comment: yes but with the second example you save the index of the min and not the value, i need to have the value because in my algorithm i have 5 variables and each a corrisponds to 5 position in the space. How can i get the values of a not like index but like value?

Comment: it's difficult to help you since you didn't provide a runable example

Comment: oh my god, i said a runable example. You should simplify your code as much as possible, keep only the parts that you wanna ask. Btw, you didn't mention about the most important part (your `while-loop`). What is your condition for the while-loop? How did you perform the while-loop etc...

Comment: for the second example, I think I saved both m(a) and temp(a), if m(a) is the index and not the value, then you should fix the function to give both the value and the index, so something like [temp(a), m(a), value(a)] = min (fiteness_pers)